# Testing a Payable Function in Solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle

So I'm trying to test a payable function on the following smart contract here using the truffle framework:

```
contract FundMe {
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;
    address public owner;
    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;

    constructor(address _priceFeed) public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        uint256 mimimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
        require(
            getConversionRate(msg.value) >= mimimumUSD,
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        );
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }
```

I specifically want to test the payable function, and I've seen a few things on the internet where people create other contracts with initial balances and then send their testing contract some eth. But I would just like to grab a local ganache wallet and send some eth to the contract and then test that, if someone could show me some test javascript code to wrap my head around this that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a contract to be able to receive ETH (or any native token - BNB on Binance Smart Chain, TRX on Tron network, ...) **without invoking any function**, you need to define at least one of these functions `receive()` ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#receive-ether-function)) or `fallback()` ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#fallback-function)).

```
contract FundMe {

    // intentionally missing the `function` keyword
    receive() external payable {
        // can be empty
    }

    // ... rest of your code
}
```

Then you can send a regular transaction to the contract address in truffle ([docs](http://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#sending-ether-triggering-the-fallback-function)):

```
const instance = await MyContract.at(contractAddress);
await instance.send(web3.toWei(1, "ether"));
```

Note that because `receive()` and `fallback()` are not regular functions, you **cannot** invoke them using the truffle autogenerated methods: `myContract.functionName()`

---

If you want to **execute a payable function** sending it ETH, you can use the `transaction params` ([docs](http://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts#making-a-transaction)). It's always the last argument, after all of the regular function arguments.

```
const instance = await MyContract.at(contractAddress);
await instance.fund({
    value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")
});
```

Note: If the `fund()` function had 1 argument (let's say a `bool`), the `transaction params` would be the 2nd:

```
await instance.fund(true, {
    value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")
});
```

Comment: So if I wanted to do something like update a given variable or forward it to another function it would happen within that receive function?

Comment: @SonnyVesali I updated my answer with this case as well. At first, I understood your question as only sending ETH to the contract without executing any function.

Comment: Is this the only way to pay ETH to a contract now? Previously, `payable` could be marked on any function, but I was getting an unexplainable revert error with the latest Solidity version prior to changing my `payable` function to `receive() external payable`.

Comment: @Neo You can use the `payable` modifier on any function. The revert that you got seems to be unrelated to the function being `payable`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to make a test on receive() function.
If you also here from FCC course, the receive() should call fund() function and add person to a list of funders if he sends enough ETH. So to test this I came up with this code:

```
let user

beforeEach(async function () {
    user = (await getNamedAccounts()).user
    // ...
    // ...

})

describe("receive", async function () {
        it("Checks if the Receive function trigers fund", async function () {
            const fundMeAdress = await fundMe.getAddress()
            signer = await ethers.getSigner(user)
            const transactionReceiveHash = await signer.sendTransaction({
                to: fundMeAdress,
                value: sendValue,
            })
            assert.equal(user, await fundMe.funders(0))
        })
    })
```